# Assigning function parameters using variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

I am trying to make a simple piece of JavaScript code, where the user puts in the length and width of a box, and the computer calculates the area of the box for them. What I did is assign the function parameters  to (length, width) and then I made two variables that would be assigned to what the user put in for the length and width. After the user has input the length and width, I called the function and assigned it's parameters to the two length and width variables. Next I made a confirm part, that took the end result of the function and displayed it.

```
//Telling the computer what to do with the length and width.
var area = function (length, width) {
    return length * width;
};

//Asking the user what the length and width are, and assigning the answers to the function.
var l = prompt("What is the length of the box?");
var w = prompt("What is the width of the box?");
area(l, w);

//Showing the end-result.
confirm("The area is:" + " " + area);
```

What happens is, the end result shows

The area is: function (length, width) {
     return length * width;\
}

So the end result of the code is showing the stuff to the right of the equals sign, as if what is written there is a string. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is pass the function named `area` to the function named `confirm`. You want instead, to pass the result of *calling* the function named `area` to the function named `confirm`

```
confirm("The area is:" + area(l, w));
```

Or alternatively:

```
var result = area(l, w);
confirm("The area is: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result to another variable:

```
var calculated_area = area(l, w);

confirm("The area is: " + calculated_area);
```

What you saw is that the variable `area` contains the function, not the value that it returns.